# Have Aurelia Custom Element Data Generated By Markup

Tags: javascript, html, templating, aurelia

Basically, I would like to be able to set up a grid with Aurelia with markup similar to this...

```
    <grid rows.bind="data" rows-per-page="10">
      <columns>
        <column header="Column One" sortable="true" property="someProp"></column>
        <column header="Column Two" sortable="true" property="someOtherProp"></column>
      </columns>
    </grid>
```

I have a custom element for the grid and the column elements, and the grid has a "columns" array for storing column elements. I would like two column entities to be created and stored in the columns array.

My question is whether or not there is currently a way to do this (or something similar) in Aurelia , where the data is created by what is entered in the markup and subsequently used by the element.

Comment: I think this blog post should help you accomplish your goal: http://patrickwalters.net/wielding-the-power-of-aurelia-content-selectors/

Comment: @AshleyGrant from what I gather, that would allow me to inject the markup from the user into the template for the element, but I still don't see how that content would be used to populate the array...

Comment: This gist from a community member might help you accomplish that part. Charles created a wrapper around the kendo grid: https://gist.github.com/CharlesPockert/1ef96e44f3f15ab60f5e

Comment: @AshleyGrant ahh, looks like he's manually parsing the content. I was hoping there was a way to accomplish this via built-in Aurelia functionality, but that works too.